# My node mcu isnt turning on when connecting 3.3V to VIN

Tags: voltage, amperage, 3.3v, nodemcu

So I'm trying to wire my node MCU using in with 3.3V and in the multimeter, it's reading the 3.3V being delivered properly by the converter, I also tested for amperage and its consuming 37mA and I don't know why it's not turning on when connected.

I'm using a 5V to 3.3V converter with up to 1A of current delivery so I suppose that's not the problem.

In case you're wondering when to connect using the USB to my PC it turns on properly.

What can be the problem with this? Should I buy a new one?

Comment: At first, if properly wired, a device should work. If yours is not working, the chip can be faulty, or there is an error in the wiring. But the way that you described the question turns impossibly to help you.

Comment: What do you need more?

Comment: @DeadSec: A wiring diagram might be very helpful. Just to see if we might miss something important. Also helpful are pictures, because not every detail of a setup is properly described with words or schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns on when powered through USB, so, it seems that the chip isnt't dead.

How did you wired it? Are you connecting 3.3V to 3.3V NodeMCU's pins?

The correct way of powering a NodeMCU is with +5V in Vin; it has a onboard voltage regulator, the same one that converts USB's 5V.

If the board is powered with 5V, 3.3v pins are outputs of the onboard voltage regulator, that could be used for powering 3.3V sensors.

Comment: So should I wire 5V to the VIN? I tried that but I broke a board once and after some research in the internet, it says that I should power the VIN with max 3.6V.

Comment: BTW I'm not sure if it was because if the voltage or other thing that may have caused that issue.

Comment: Don't read the internet. Read the manual how it is supposed to be powered and with what voltages.

Comment: [This page](https://www.make-it.ca/nodemcu-arduino/nodemcu-details-specifications/) and many others say that 3.3V pins are just the output of the onboard regulator, [the schematic](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=7026&start=4) shows that ESP12 is powered from VDD3V3. This infirms my previous asserting that the board should not be powered from 3v3 pins. I edited the answer.

Comment: Connected to 5V worked thanks.